# errors in live logs - live support - how do you do it?

Tags: java, exception

we have different live plattforms ranging from pure java stacks to angularjs and others. we get loads of error in different logs from typical java exceptions to client side error messages send to our log service.

we weren't able to cleanup all error and exceptions in the past so we currently have a big mess and have to deal with it.

so my question ist: how are you dealing with exception, more specifically:

- who spots them? (kibana, logstash, graphite, error mails ...)
- who deals with them (prio, age etc., 1-n developers, devops?), especially during tight scrum sprints?
- how do you keep track of improvements in this area?

so the questions would really be: "how are your developers able to deal with exceptions during scrum sprints"?

would be nice to get your ideas on this.

any help highly appreciated

cheers
marcel

Comment: my suggestions will be : 1) Do a full stack rigorous testing before you release the product 2) Have ops check the logs regularly and escalate the errors to developers 3) DO not rush for the bug fix releases , maintain a schedule and release the fixes on the schedule only

Comment: thanks for your comment. we already to _a_lot_ of testing and continious integration with loads of unit, integration and gui testing. but live systems are a different animal. we do a scheduled deployment every 3 weeks. the question remains: what about developers during tight sprints?